# Using filter_at to filter some data correctly

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I am trying to use the `filter_at` function from the `tidyverse`/`dplyr`. What I want to do is to filter `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`,  and `Petal.Width` without actually specifying the names or in a way that I can specify some variables I do not want to filter. i.e. Below I do not want to filter `Sepal.Length` and `Species`.

I am tyring to filter out all the data which is greater than 3 and less than 2. (Just keeping the observations between 2.9999 an 2.00001 etc.

```
data(iris)
iris %>% 
  filter_at(vars(-Sepal.Length, -Species), all_vars(. > 3 & < 2))
```

Additionally I would like to filter and `Inf` observations also. `any_vars(is.Inf(.))` across all variables.

Comment: You're making the classic (easy to make) mistake of specifying the observations you want to remove, but `filter` expects you to specify the observations you want to keep.

Comment: Oh I see. I don't mind specifying the variables I want to keep but I kind of wanted to make it dynamic since I might add variables to the data, so I didn't want to change the `filter_at` each time I add a new variable. Is it possible to use something like `vars(Sepal.Width:ncol(.))`

Comment: Sorry--either you're misunderstanding me or I'm misunderstanding your goal. I think your `vars(-Sepal.Length, -Species)` is working just fine. Do you want to change that? Where I see the issue is `. > 3 & < 2`. You have 2 issues there. 1: bad syntax, you would need `. > 3 & . < 2`, you can't use `& <` directly. 2: bad logic, nothing can be greater than 3 *and* less than 2 - this is where I mean you are specifying the obs you want to remove. You want to keep obs between 2 and 3, so change to `2 < . & . < 3`, specifying what you want to keep, not what you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think this gets what I need `iris %>% 
  filter_at(vars(-Sepal.Length, -Species), all_vars(. > 3 | . < 2))`.